# definite vs indefinite article usage corrector

Tags: python, text, nlp

I'm writing a program that corrects 'a/an' vs 'the' article usage . I've been able to detect case of plurality ( article is always 'the' when the corresponding noun is plural ) .

I'm stumped on how to solve this issue for singular nouns. Without context, both "an apple" and the "apple" are correct. How would I approach such cases ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is something you will be able to get 100% accuracy on, but it seems to me that one of the most important cues is previous mention. If no apple has been mentioned before, then it is a little odd to say 'the apple'.

A very cheap (and less accurate) approach is to literally check for a token 'apple' in the preceding context and use that as a feature, possibly in conjunction with many other features, such as:

- position in text (definiteness becomes likelier as the text progresses)
- grammatical function via a dependency parse (grammatical subjects more likely to be definite)
- phrase length (definite mentions are typically shorter, fewer adjectives)
- etc. etc.

A better but more complex approach would be to insert "the" and then use a coreference resolution component to attempt to find a previous mention. Although automatic coreference resolution is not perfect, it is the best way to determine if there is a previous mention using NLP, and most systems will also attempt to resolve non-trivial cases, such as `"John has Malaria ... the disease"`, which a simple string lookup will miss, as well as distiguishing non-co-referring mentions: `a red apple ... != a green apple`.

Finally, there is a large amount of nouns which can appear with an article despite not being mentioned previously, including names ("the Olympic Games"), generics ("the common ant"), contextually inferable words ("pass the salt") and uniquely identifiable ("the sun"). All of these could be learned from a training corpus, but that would probably require a separate classifier.

Hope this helps!